# Why is my test failing on an expectation wrapped in `waitFor()`?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following utility function that I use in all my tests:

```js
async function waitForContentLoaded() {
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.queryByRole('progressbar')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
}
```

Now 2 out of 37 tests fail with the error message `expected document not to contain element, found <span {...} role="progressbar" {...} />`, and a stacktrace pointing to the expectation above.

Isn't `waitFor()` supposed to catch these errors, and then try again until it doesn't throw?

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what [the documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) says:

> `waitFor` may run the callback a number of times until the timeout is reached. Note that the number of calls is constrained by the `timeout` and `interval` options.

> The default `interval` is `50ms`. However it will run your callback immediately before starting the intervals.

> The default `timeout` is `1000ms`.

So, on the final invocation before the `timeout` value is exceeded, `waitFor` will reject with any exception which occurs in the callback you provide to it.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!